# Looking inside of a folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, listdir

I am trying to get this script to loop through the directory I am looking at, once it has passed validation.

The code checks to see if the folder name (seperated by '-'), is made up from digits, and if those digits are 5 characters long in total. Once this check
has been done, I want my code to loop through that folder.

Can anyone help me?

This is my code so far:

```
directory = r'\\cd3\SFTP'

for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    folder = folder.split(' - ')
    #print fn
    if 'infognana' in folder or 'sunriseimaging' in folder or 'mydatasolutions' in folder:
        continue
    if folder[0].isdigit() and len(folder[0]) == 5:
        print folder
```

Comment: What is it you now want to check?

Comment: so basically you want to check in every folder that you find with 5 digits

Comment: @NitaAlexandru yeah, so it checks the first folder to see if it has 5 digits at the start of its name and if so it's valid. Then it checks the folders in the valid folder to see if they're 10 digits long. And it will print out all that aren't.

Comment: What is your operating system ?

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi Windows 10.

Comment: Do you want to check inside of the folders which satisfied the `if folder[0].isdigit() and len(folder[0]) == 5:` condition, or any folder's inside should be checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code which **recursively** crawls your folders and prints the name of folders which start with a digit and are 5 characters long.

```
import os  
def check(dir):
for f in [x for x in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isdir(dir+"/{}".format(x))]:
    if any([i in folder_name for i in \ 
                ['infognana', 'sunriseimaging', 'mydatasolutions']]):
    if f[0].isdigit() and len(f)==5:
        print f                     # print the name of the (sub)folder
        check(os.path.join(dir, f)  # do the same thing for this subfolder
```

You  told you want to check **folders** (not files), so we need to skip files. This is done by using `os.path.isdir` in the above code, line 3.
Each **subfolder** is printed **just in case** its parrent satisfied the conditions of starting with a digit and being 5 characters long.
I checked and ran the above code on ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2):

As you know, if you have the folder name, then you can just use `os.listdir(folder_name)` to "look inside"

The only issue in your code is, that you loose the folder name of the current folder you are looking at, since you are overwriting it with the split result:

```
folder = folder.split(' - ')
```

If you save the original folder name, then you can the call os.listdir and perform your actions:

```
for folder_name in os.listdir(directory):
    folder = folder_name.split(' - ')
    #print fn
    if 'infognana' in folder or 'sunriseimaging' in folder or 'mydatasolutions' in folder:
        continue
    if folder[0].isdigit() and len(folder[0]) == 5:
        #do something on os.listdir(os.path.join(directory,folder_name))
        print folder
```

Comment: Okay, I've done that as I realised what you meant. Listdir needed an obvious full path to check inside of the folders. However now I'm getting the error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dlogan\Desktop\Scripts\SFTP Script\#2\SFTP Script #2.py", line 42, in <module>
    folder2 = os.listdir(folder_name)
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '10324 - Waste Care/*.*'**

Comment: Use `os.path.join(directory,folder_name)`